# Vue.js and input's value that is never displayed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making a simple shopping list app in Vue.js and I was curious if there's a standard way of doing what I need to do. I have a list of items with add and delete buttons:

[image: Shopping List app]

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        items: [
            'Chocolate',
            'Pizza',
            'Coca-Cola',
        ],
        newItem: ''
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            <div>{{ items.length }} item{{ items.length !== 1 ? 's' : '' }}</div>
            <ul>
                <li v-for="(item, index) of items">
                    {{ item }}
                    <button @click="deleteItem(index)">X</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" v-model="newItem" placeholder="Item name">
                    <button @click="addItem">+</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `,
    methods: {
        addItem() {
            const item = this.newItem.trim();
            if (item === '') return;
            this.items.push(item);
            this.newItem = '';
        },
        deleteItem(index) {
            this.items.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

It works just as it should, but I'm not sure about using data entry that is never displayed anywhere. There's also another approach with `$refs`:

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        items: [
            'Chocolate',
            'Pizza',
            'Coca-Cola',
        ],
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            <div>{{ items.length }} item{{ items.length !== 1 ? 's' : '' }}</div>
            <ul>
                <li v-for="(item, index) of items">
                    {{ item }}
                    <button @click="deleteItem(index)">X</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Item name" ref="newItem">
                    <button @click="addItem($refs.newItem.value)">+</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `,
    methods: {
        addItem(item) {
            item = item.trim();
            if (item === '') return;
            this.items.push(item);
            this.$refs.newItem.value = '';
        },
        deleteItem(index) {
            this.items.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

Instead of using separate data entry and `v-model`, I'm using `$refs` directly. Is any of these approaches more widely accepted in Vue.js community or guidelines? Or perhaps there's even more popular way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to share my views here. Personally I like to use `v-model` as it provides few added benefits like:

- We can use [`.trim`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#trim) modifier with `v-model` which automatically trims whitespace from user input like:

  ```
    <input v-model.trim="msg">
  ```

This way you don't need to write additional code to trim text like `item = item.trim();`. Few lines of code saved here.

- Using `this.newItem = ''` we can easily clear out the previously entered text after button click using `v-model` reactivity feature. So, again less line of code instead of doing `this.$refs.newItem.value = '';`
- Another advantage of using `v-model` is that, instead of doing

  ```
    <button @click="addItem($refs.newItem.value)">
  ```

You can simply call the function like:

```
    <button @click="addItem">
```

So, you can see these are the few benefits of using a simple `v-model`, which is mostly related to the developer experience (DX) point of view.

**Working Demo:**

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        items: [
            'Chocolate',
            'Pizza',
            'Coca-Cola',
        ],
        newItem: ''
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            <div>{{ items.length }} item{{ items.length !== 1 ? 's' : '' }}</div>
            <ul>
                <li v-for="(item, index) of items">
                    {{ item }}
                    <button @click="deleteItem(index)">X</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Item name" v-model.trim="newItem">
                    <button @click="addItem">+</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `,
    methods: {
        addItem() {
            if (this.newItem === '') return;
            this.items.push(this.newItem);
            this.newItem = '';
        },
        deleteItem(index) {
            this.items.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: It adds some practical convenience for sure. How do you feel about having a piece of `data` that is not meaningful per se though? It serves as a temporary value other than something our app relies on. It it "normal" to use `data` for such a thing? Also, I'm afraid I'll need to use `$refs` anyway, because I'll be focusing that input after adding an item. To be clear: I'm leaning towards `v-model` myself, just thinking out loud here :)

Comment: I mostly go for the better DX and better code readability, as when you added the ref, other devs would have to scan the whole template to see where is the ref attached actually, or use ctrl+F.. but with v-model I know it's going to be in one place only. Also, based on your DOM manipulation requirement it would be better to use ref, but we can also do this by creating custom directives, but for smaller apps its more important to focus on functionality first, then trying to make it better and better over several iterations.